# how do you synchronize rviz publishing?

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All the code examples I see online use a clock with a time guesstimate for rviz to finish loading before sending markers by publishing.

Is there a better way to tell when rviz has finished loading than sleeping for xxxxseconds?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251672/how-do-you-synchronize-rviz-publishing-?/) by [rosnutsbolts](https://answers.ros.org/users/28002/rosnutsbolts/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-01-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You don't link to any of the examples, but I'm guessing that what they're really waiting for is for the topic setup to finish, and for rviz to be subscribed before they start publishing. (particularly because rviz is often running before the marker node starts)

The other typical way to do this is to wait for at least one subscriber to be connected to your topic. There are methods on the roscpp and rospy publisher objects to get the number of connected subscribers.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0